# View in Viewcontroller disappears

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, connection

Having a bug when i try to delete viewcontroller2 which is connected to vc1. Part of the view in viewcontroller1 seems to disappear even though i remove all connections. Ran in to this problem before on same project when connections were not right.

The first image is how it is supposed to be with listname and a button in lower corner.

The last image is how the tableview looks like when i try to remove the other vc.

Any idea of how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"when i try to delete vc2 "_… what does that mean? Where's your code?

Comment: erase one of the viewcontrollers completely

Comment: It' still unclear what you mean - you have to show the code you're using to do this. Don't make us guess what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but try putting this in the function for when vc2 closes:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.view = nil
```

If you provide some code it will be easier to understand.